# My Twitter timeline has a huge 11 hour period of silence. Can I retrieve those tweets anyhow?

Tags: twitter

There is an ~11h period of silence in my Twitter timeline:

[image]

Why is this happening and is there any way to retrieve the missing tweets? (My timeline usually contains around ~480 tweets per day, so I estimate that at least 200 tweets are missing.)

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your browser? A hard refresh?

Comment: @Sathya Yes. Note though that this data isn't retrieved on page load (statically), rather it's Ajax data (retrieved via JavaScript), and is therefore not cached. I load the Twitter home page and start scrolling to the bottom (or press END) and Twitter loads new data in batches of 20 tweets (every time I reach the page bottom). Those 11 missing hours are just skipped in this process.

Comment: Where you ever able to see what was in those missing hours?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise No. I tried a bunch of times and if I recall correctly, I was able to retrieve a bunch of additional tweets, but not most of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to fetch data via API with any backup service, e.g. [Backupify for Personal Apps](https://www.backupify.com/products/personal-apps-backup) - basic account is free.

If it fetches data down that date and 11 hour hole is present in backup too, then it is loss on Twitter side which you most probably won't be able to recover. Still you can ask Twitter then.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I have succeeded in refreshing is logging out and logging back in.